# ag-grid auto height for entire grid

Tags: ag-grid

I can't find a good way to size the grid to fit all rows perfectly.

[documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-width-and-height/#gsc.tab=0) only points to sizing by % or px.

Since I want it to size based on rows, I came up with the following function. Seem like im re-inventing the wheel, so maybe there is a better way?

```
getHeight(type:EntityType) {
    var c = this.Apis[type] && this.Apis[type].api && this.Apis[type].api.rowModel // get api for current grid
        ? this.Apis[type].api.rowModel.rowsToDisplay.length
        : -1;
    return c > 0
        ? (40+(c*21))+'px' // not perfect but close formula for grid height
        : '86%';
}
```

there has to be a less messy way..

Comment: This seems to be the right approach, though I don't see why you are doing the various checks on whether the api exists or not... Do you need to change the grid height after filtering? or are you just using this one time for the initial grid creation?

Comment: because api gets initialized with the grid during load time. can't be certain getHeight gets called after it is initialized properly.

Comment: if you use the `onGridReady` event, then you wouldn't need to check if the api exists since that fires only after it does exist.

Comment: I am binding this property to a UI element using [style.height]="getHeight()". it's up to that UI element to call this property whenever it needs to. not sure what onGridReady has to do with it

Comment: Are you changing the grid's height anytime that a filter is applied?

Comment: i'm hoping that it will trigger a resize yes

Comment: can you have a look at once on my query - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691754/angular-ag-grid-attach-class-to-grouped-rows-cell-based-on-validation-of-other-c

Answer (score 12):

I came across this solution:

- https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/801

There are 2 answers to this problem.

1) If you are using anything below v10.1.0, then you can use the following CSS to achieve the problem:

```
.ag-scrolls {
    height: auto !important;
}

.ag-body {
    position: relative !important;
    top: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
}

.ag-header { 
    position: relative !important;
}

.ag-floating-top {
    position: relative !important;
    top: auto !important;
}

.ag-floating-bottom {
    position: relative !important;
    top: auto !important;
}

.ag-bl-normal-east,
.ag-bl-normal,
.ag-bl-normal-center,
.ag-bl-normal-center-row,
.ag-bl-full-height,
.ag-bl-full-height-center,
.ag-pinned-left-cols-viewport,
.ag-pinned-right-cols-viewport,
.ag-body-viewport-wrapper,
.ag-body-viewport {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

2) Anything above v10.1.0, there is now a property called 'domLayout'.

- https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-width-and-height/#autoHeight

Comment: Thanks, this helped me with an issue i was having with `autoHeight` not acting the same in all browsers when using pinned columns

Answer (score 8):

If the following is the markup

```
<ag-grid-angular
  #agGrid
  id="myGrid"
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  [domLayout]="domLayout"
  [animateRows]="true"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

Note that **[domLayout]="domLayout"**

set it as     **this.domLayout = "autoHeight";** and you're done..

Ref:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-width-and-height/

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Jb1TD7gbA4w7yclU

Hope it helps.

Comment: domLayout won't work for large number of rows. And I have over 4000 rows. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Hi! Hey in the plunker there, if you look at the filters by clicking in the headers, you cna see the the overflow of filter pop-ups is hidden. You know how that have them be visible ?

Comment: @user8750012 the grid docs suggest the large numbers of rows are not a grid limit but a browser limit: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grid-size/

Comment: Please don't default to domLayout = "autoHeight" because of convenience. I'd take a quick look at the cpu on Performance monitor in your devtools with autoHeight on and off. It's gonna drain your clients cellphone-batteries faster than you can say "autoHeight"

Answer (score 3):

Call this method after the data loads to the grid:

```
determineHeight() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount());
      if (this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount() < 20) {
        this.gridApi.setDomLayout("autoHeight");
      }
      else {
        this.gridApi.setDomLayout("normal");
        document.getElementById('myGrid').style.height = "600px";
      }
    }, 500);
  }
```

Comment: Call this method after the data loads to the grid.

Comment: That comment would be better as a part of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can now automate grid height by setting the `domLayout='autoHeight'` property, or by calling `api.setDomLayout('autoHeight')`

reference [Grid Auto Height](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/grid-size/#grid-auto-height)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code on **onGridReady** function for auto width and auto height

```
onGridReady = params => {
   // Following line to make the currently visible columns fit the screen  
   params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();

   // Following line dymanic set height to row on content
   params.api.resetRowHeights();
};
```

reference
[Auto Height](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-height/#auto-row-height)
[Auto width](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/#size-columns-to-fit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ag-grid` feature `AutoHeight = true` in the column Configuration. or if you want to calculate the height dynamically you should use `getRowHeight()` callback and create DOM elements like `div` and `span`, and add your text in it, then the `div` will give the `OffsetHeight` for it then you wont see any cropping of data/rows.

Hope this helps.